# How to deploy Machine Learning based Android app?

Tags: android, machine-learning, deployment, architecture

I am trying to build an image editing app, that uses Machine Learning models. I have the model trained in Google compute engine. I am planning to release the android app in the play store to the public. In order to do that, Is it wise to place the model in the android app? Will it be compute-intensive for mobile phones? or place it in the cloud and create APIs to use them? Is there a better way to deploy ML models?

Comment: Hi @desertnaut, Nowhere did I mention the word programming in my question or in my tags, Can you please mention where I'm supposed to change the settings for this question?

Comment: This is exactly the issue with the question. The meaning of the comment is that, since SO is about *specific programming* questions (and not, say, general advice on apps development or placing), the question is off-topic here; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (as also implicitly advised in the comment).

Comment: Hi @desertnaut, Thanks for the help. As mentioned in the link you specified, "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" The wording does not mean that the question should be about programming only. And which part in my question makes you feel that it is about a specific programming language? In the question, I'm asking for a way to architect my solution. The phrase "Is it wise? Will it be intensive? Is it better?" are all Yes/No questions. It's not about any specific programming language. Please read the question again. :)

Comment: In any case, a minority of experienced users here at SO (myself included) deliberately choose to comment in questions by new users in order to give guidance on why their question is not a good fit for SO, thus offering advice for potential improvements *before* their question simply gets closed. It's true that the majority of us believe that such comments is a waste of our time, and that OP's seldom listen to such advice; you may find the [discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390784/how-should-i-send-help-links-to-new-users/390786#390786) enlightening...

Comment: Oh, I just got enlightened. Thanks to @desertnaut. Even I think your comment was a waste of time. Thanks for the help anyway. Have a great day! :)